# the site won't let me enter code in the bow without an error

Tags: java, event-handling, keylistener

I want to be able to press the e key when an input box pops up and closes the program without errors. Currently, I have to type e and hit enter when the j option pane box pops up. I have been trying to use Key Listener, but I don't seem to know how to code it with J Option Pane.

```
String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Number of Properties");
if ( num.contentEquals("E"))
    System.exit(0);
else if (num.contentEquals("e"))
    System.exit(0); 

int a = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

Comment: This is a personal project. I can produce the whole code if asked for

Comment: Well, I found a way to do this which is _horrible_ (get the `JTextField` from the `BasicOptionPaneUI` of a `JOptionPane` using reflection, and add a `KeyListener` to that)...  I'll add an answer containing it if you just want _a_ (read, _definitely_ not the right or best) solution to it.  Otherwise I'll let other people answer :).

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/rxxMxzB5) is the horrible code for the record.  If you're happy with that approach, le'mme know and I'll move to an answer with some better effort to make it readable/explain the issue.  (Sorry for potentially sketchy pastebin link.)

Comment: Why not just have an Exit button in your Input Dialog box?